# Is there a way to consume sample records from kinesis?

Tags: java, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kcl

I wrote an Amazon Kinesis consumer using KCL, which manages my record processing task. It is currently processing the records without filtering. 
I am looking for a way to process sample records while skipping some of them.

For example, in case there are 100 records total, and I would like to process just 1/10 out of it (10 sample records).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there's no way to tell Kinesis only to return a random subset of records. So it's up to you to ignore records once they've been returned to you.

In the `processRecords` method, simply ignore 9/10 records randomly:

```java
public void processRecords(ProcessRecordsInput processRecordsInput) {
    processRecordsInput.records()
            .forEach(r -> if (generateRandomNumber()%10 == 0) process(r));
}

private int generateRandomNumber() {
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.nextInt(10);
}
```